# California CARB converter list by the CA Air Resource Board is no longer available

Tags: exhaust, catalytic-converter

The only CARB listed converters by California is AP Exhaust 749233 Direct Fit and 740566 single replacement are no longer available.  I called AP Exhaust and they are closed down and not sure if they will open.  I can find single converters that say they are CARB or California legal, but are not listed by the State.  Is it legal to install one of these?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!